# Desarrollo de una app en flutter

Tags: flutter

Hola tengo un inconveniente con el siguiente error ya que estoy tratando de llamar una propiedad del modelo MedidorUser pero no se por que no me muestra esa lista  :

> `The getter 'logs' isn't defined for the type 'List<MedidorUser>'. Try importing the library that defines 'logs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'logs'`

dicho error me aparece en un FutureBuilder que estoy implementando en mi app el cual es el siguiente:

```
FutureBuilder<List<MedidorUser>?>(
                  future: medidorUser,
                  builder: (context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<List<MedidorUser>?> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return const Text(
                        'Sin Información',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      print('abajo se imprime lo del detalle');

                      detalle = snapshot.data!.logs;
                      print(detalle);
                      return const SingleChildScrollView();
                    }
                  },
                )
```

este error aparece en la siguiente línea ya que estoy intentando acceder a logs con la variable detalle y no se por que no me muestra **logs**:

```
detalle = snapshot.data!.logs;
```

ya que logs es la lista del modelo:

```
    import 'dart:convert';

List<MedidorUser> getMedidorUserFromJson(String str) => List<MedidorUser>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => MedidorUser.fromJson(x)));

String getMedidorUserToJson(List<MedidorUser> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class MedidorUser {
  MedidorUser({
    this.psiId,
    this.psi,
    this.concesionId,
    this.concesion,
    this.rfc,
    this.razonSocial,
    this.logs,
  });

  int? psiId;
  String? psi;
  int? concesionId;
  String? concesion;
  String? rfc;
  String? razonSocial;
  List<Log>? logs;

  factory MedidorUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MedidorUser(
        psiId: json["psi_id"] ?? 0,
        psi: json["psi"] ?? "",
        concesionId: json["concesion_id"] ?? 0,
        concesion: json["concesion"] ?? "",
        rfc: json["rfc"] ?? "",
        razonSocial: json["razon_social"] ?? "",
        logs: List<Log>.from(json["logs"].map((x) => Log.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "psi_id": psiId,
        "psi": psi,
        "concesion_id": concesionId,
        "concesion": concesion,
        "rfc": rfc,
        "razon_social": razonSocial,
        "logs": List<dynamic>.from(logs!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

List<Log> getLogFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Log>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Log.fromJson(x)));

String getLogToJson(List<Log> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Log {
  Log({
    this.rfc,
    this.nsm,
    this.nsue,
    this.lat,
    this.long,
    this.modeloId,
    this.modelo,
    this.ccid,
    this.imei,
    this.nsut,
    this.etiqueta,
    this.fecha,
    this.history,
  });

  String? rfc;
  String? nsm;
  String? nsue;
  double? lat;
  double? long;
  int? modeloId;
  String? modelo;
  String? ccid;
  String? imei;
  String? nsut;
  String? etiqueta;
  DateTime? fecha;
  dynamic history;

  factory Log.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Log(
        rfc: json["rfc"] ?? "",
        nsm: json["nsm"] ?? "",
        nsue: json["nsue"] ?? "",
        lat: json["lat"] ?? 0.0.toDouble(),
        long: json["long"] ?? 0.0.toDouble(),
        modeloId: json["modelo_id"] ?? 0,
        modelo: json["modelo"] ?? "",
        ccid: json["ccid"] ?? "",
        imei: json["imei"] ?? "",
        nsut: json["nsut"] ?? "",
        etiqueta: json["etiqueta"] ?? "",
        fecha: json["fecha"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["fecha"]),
        history: json["history"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rfc": rfc,
        "nsm": nsm,
        "nsue": nsue,
        "lat": lat,
        "long": long,
        "modelo_id": modeloId,
        "modelo": modelo,
        "ccid": ccid,
        "imei": imei,
        "nsut": nsut,
        "etiqueta": etiqueta,
        "fecha": fecha == null ? null : fecha!.toIso8601String(),
        "history": history,
      };
}
```

y para hacer la llamada de esa lista utilizo estas variables

```
Future<List<MedidorUser>?>? medidorUser;
List<MedidorUser>? listaMedidoresUser;
  List<Log>? detalle;
```

ya llevo rato intentando solucionarlo pero no puedo ojala me puedan ayudar y de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La clave del fallo está en el tipo del

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<MedidorUser>?>(
    [...]
)
```

El tipo es **<List<MedidorUser>?>** por tanto, la variable `data` no es de tipo `MedidorUser`, sino de tipo `List<T>` donde `T` es `MedidorUser`. Y la clase `List`, no tiene la propiedad `logs`, por tanto, es lógico que no puedas acceder a dicha propiedad.

Tendrás que acceder a los elementos de la lista para poder visualizar los logs. Por ejemplo, algo así:

`final detalle = snapshot.data![0].logs;`

Donde 0 indica que queremos acceder a la primera posición de la lista.

Otra opción podría ser hacer un `for` para recorrer todos los elementos de la lista y acceder a la propiedad `logs` de cada uno.

Comment: Gracias Amigo por la ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta te ayuda, podrías marcarla como la correcta ^^.